# Prevent Hibernate from generating duplicate foreign keys on table?

Tags: spring, hibernate

Our site uses Spring (5.2.8.RELEASE), Hibernate (5.4.19.Final), Tomcat (8.5.x), and SQL Server (2014). Recently, we noticed that the performance is bad in case of deleting a simple record. We found out that it is caused by duplicate foreign keys that were generated by Hibernate. When there is a new table or field, we let Hibernate generate needed new tables or keys (primary key or foreign key) by setting

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

This is only a one-time deal. After generating new tables or new keys, we prohibit Hibernate from updating any tables or keys by setting

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=none
```

However, hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update generates duplicate foreign keys on existing tables. For example, the site allows people to leave comments and upvote/downvote comments. Upvote/downvote table has references to Comment and Account tables, recording which comment was upvoted/downvoted and who did the vote.

Here is the code about the relationship between Vote and Account in Java. In CommentVote.java

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "account")
private Account account;
```

In Account.java:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "account", targetEntity = CommentVote.class, 
fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<CommentVote> commentVotes;
```

Here is what is shown in SQL Management Studio:

[image]

In the above picture, foreign key FK17o46... and FKmgsaf... are duplicates. For example, the foreign keys on the Account field:

[image]

[image]

If we delete the two duplicate keys and set hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update, then the they will be generated again. How can we prevent Hibernate from generating duplicate foreign keys if they already exist on tables while still letting it generating keys only for NEW tables or NEW fields?

Comment: Are these inverse relationships? You don’t supply much info about the nature of the foreign keys or the mappings.

Comment: Thanks for the question! I updated the post with two screenshots showing the foreign keys on the same Account field.

Comment: I just realized this as well and would love to fix it. Look into @UniqueConstraint anotation.

Comment: @I_AM__PAUL, thanks for your input. The foreign key issue I have is not about unique key. I tested UniqueConstraint and it didn't work. Did you have a working example?

Comment: Sorry for long reply. Did not properly test ist.

In my case this one worked : 

@JoinColumn(name = "zone_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_DeviceZone", value = ConstraintMode.PROVIDER_DEFAULT))
private Zone zone;

Comment: Hibernate generates an MD5 hash out of several values including the involved table names to generate a foreign key constraint name, if no name was specified in the JPA annotations. For some databases it seems to rely on this name to verify the presence of a foreign key and if it can't find it, it will then try to create it. This results in the duplicate key issue you experience. I have not found a solution to this problem either, without specifying the constraint in the annotation.